# Should I validate foreign keys in a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the following simplified models

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :article
  validates :tag_id, :article_id, presence: true
end
```

I pretty much followed the [tagging railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) except I'm trying to write tests for it.

The validation in the Tagging model, which is not used in the railscast, but which I have added myself, is causing me some headaches.

If I create a new article, I can pass a list of tags:

```
a = Article.new(title: "title", tag_list: "tag 1, tag 2")
a.valid? 
#=> false 
a.errors
# => 
  @base=#<Article id: nil, title: "title">, 
  @messages={:taggings=>["is invalid", "is invalid"]}>
```

So it looks like the validation on my tagging class is causing Article creation to fail, because `article_id` is not yet available.

What do people usually do here? Is it customary to add such validations to join tables or can this be skipped?

Comment: what is your intention to validate these constraints? what are you expecting to fail under which circumstances? Take some minutes to think about it and try to answer the answer yourself ;-)

Hint: what happens if :tag_id or :article_id is not there?

Comment: Well, if they aren't there, the tag wouldn't show up on the screen, no big deal really. I guess it should be ok to leave these valiations out.

Comment: so there you go ;-). I would have recommended to remove them also because they do not bring any stableness to your application ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer now

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that `Tagging` validates the presence of `:tag` and `:article`, rather than the IDs. This has two benefits:

1. If the article is a new record, the `Tagging` will still be valid.
2. If the article_id is invalid (e.g. -1), the `Tagging` will be invalid.

I disagree with the previous commenters' suggestion to remove the validation altogether, validations help avoid creating bad records. E.g a `Tagging` with an article but not a tag.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for your reply, I will give it a try tomorrow, it looks like it's the best way to do it, clever idea :)